# Replace Ruby link text on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My first question here! 
**Quick outline**
Text for the submit button is created dynamically. I want to change the text on the button on hover.

```
<%= submit_tag post.date_posts.count * post.price, {:class => "btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block"} %>
```

This displays the the resulting number on the button. I want the button text to display "Apply Now" on hover. Important thing is that there are multiple job posts available on one page and every post has a different apply button with different number.

I researched and found a way to do it on a link with static text using  and css, but not sure how can I do it with ruby in it.

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, 'USD 2000'), new_user_registration_path(:user_type => "freelancer"),  class: "btn btn-danger btn-large apply-button" %>
```

This is the css:

```
.apply-button {
  width: 219px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
 }
.apply-button:hover span {
  display: none;
 }
.apply-button:hover:before {
  content: "Apply Now";
 }
```

The desired result would replace the value from ruby with "Apply Now" text on it.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: create a markup like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wxtjt94v/1/

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a `<button type="submit" />` instead:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag

```
button_tag(type: 'submit') do
  content_tag(:span, '$100')
end
```

```css
.apply-button {
  width: 219px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
 }

.apply-button:hover span {
  display: none;
 }

.apply-button:hover:before {
  content: "Apply Now";
 }
```

```html
<button type="submit" id="status" class="btn btn-danger btn-large apply-button" value="True"><span>$100</span></button>
```